# Error when adding to the domain : the specified server cannot perform the requested operation

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

When we add computers to the domain in Windows 7, we get the error:

> Changing the Primary Domain DNS name of this computer to "" failed.
>   The name will remain "domain.com".
>
> The error was:
>   The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

This happens on multiple computers and retrying yields the same result. Despite the error, the computer is still able to login to the domain ok. The DCs are windows 2003.

Has anyone found a way to get rid of this error?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[There's an MS KB about it here, but basically, it's one of those not-an-error errors](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2018583) (in your case at least).

If you still want to get rid of it, like it says in the KB, check your NETBIOS, DNS suffixing, IPv4 connectivity to the domain, and so on.